# Dart Operators : The name 'b' isn't a type and can't be used in an 'is' expression

Tags: dart, operators

I'm new to [dart](https://dart.dev/) and reading about `dart operators`. In the book `fluter in Action` **by Eric Windmill** (Chapter 2, 2.24, page 34) the auther says:

`is and is! verify that two objects are of the same type. They are equivalent to == and !=.`

Trying to implement this as shown in the code below

```dart
void main() {
    int a = 7;
    int b = 2;
    bool z = a == b; // It works when I use the equals symbol
    print('Result: $z');
}
```

But when I use the ```is`` keyword, I get an error

```
void main() {
    int a = 7;
    int b = 2;
    bool z = a is b; // It doesn't work here
    print('Result: $z');
}
```

Error

```
The name 'b' isn't a type and can't be used in an 'is' expression.
Try correcting the name to match an existing type.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what the context of that statement is but `is` and `is!` is not the same as `==` and `!=` in the sense that they does the same. I guess what the want to explain, is that the opposite of `is` is `is!` like the opposite of `==` is `!=`.

`==` is used to check if two objects are equal (based on what this object at left side defines to be equal). So for `int` we return `true` when using `==` if both numbers have the same numeric value.

The `is` operator is used to test if a given object does implement a given interface. An example:

```dart
void main() {
  Object myList = <int>[];
  
  if (myList is List<int>) {
    print('We have a list of numbers.');
  }
}
```

The error you are getting are telling you that for using `is` you need to provide an actual type at the right side of the `is` and not an object instance.

Comment: Right i see,  I confused because I come from python. In python if you have variable ```a=2``` and ```b=2``` and you run ```a is b``` this gives you the same answer like ```a==b```.

Thanks for your answer, now I understand.